non financial donations and giving back to individuals or households
How can i use civicrm  to register and keep records, of non-financial donations, like clothes, food, toys, that  someone donated to our organazation.
And after giving it it back to indiduals or households, and keep records of it?

I would probably suggest the use of activities to do this. You can create an activity type to record non financial donations. And then add some custom fields for the sorts of information you want to record specific to non financial donations.
You can have a custom field to represent the type of donation or you could create an activity type per type of donations. This sort of decision is best mad

Looks like the end of your answer got cut off, but also I don't think this will work well if they have a legal need to report on the value of the donation and/or to give tax receipts. They probably want to use contributions but with a financial type called "In-kind" or something, and then yes some custom fields related to what they need for those types of donations.
